# Local systems as a Serre subcategory of the category of perverse sheaves

Tags: rt.representation-theory, perverse-sheaves, constructible-sheaves, t-structure

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety. Let $Perv(X)$ be the (abelian) category of perverse sheaves on $X$ and let $Loc^{ft}(X)$ be the subcategory of local systems with finitely-generated stalks.

It is known that $Loc^{ft}(X)$ is a Serre subcategory of $Perv(X)$, meaning that it is closed under sub-objects and quotient objects. (See e.g. Prop 3.4.1 of Achar's book "Perverse Sheaves and Applications to Representation Theory").

More precisely, I wanted to ask whether this statement is also known to generalize to the category $Loc(X)$ of local systems with not-necessarily-finitely-generated stalks.

Following Kashiwara-Schapira's book "Sheaves on manifolds", one can consider the derived category of "weakly constructible" sheaves -- this is defined just like the usual derived category of constructible sheaves, except that now we allow the restriction to each stratum to be a local system with not-necessarily-finitely-generated stalks.  It's also possible to define the perverse t-structure so that it induces a t-structure on the category of weakly-constructible sheaves (see e.g. see e.g. Definition 10.3.7 in Kashiwara-Schapira -- the point is to avoid recourse to Verdier duality).  One thus obtains an abelian category $Perv_w(X)$, which contains $Perv(X)$ as a subcategory.

Question: is $Loc(X)$ a Serre subcategory of $Perv_w(X)$?